# Automatically make all child classes call parent's method

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, resharper

I am currently refactoring a large application.

There is a huge amount of Windows Forms, and they all inherit from one base form. I am unable to debug anything that happens after the first form is ran using Application.Run().

Since the code is a mess, I cannot easily follow the flow when debugging the UI, and do not know which form I am looking at when.

There are too many forms for me to manually create a method for each, so what I want to do is create a method in the parent class which is called by everyone. This method could for example print the form name to console. This way I can create some folder structure in the source code, based on what leads where.

Any suggestions how I could do this using Resharper and/or Visual Studio?

Any input is highly appreciated!

Comment: Creating a method in the base is fairly easy: `protected sealed void Callme() { /*... yada yada  */ }` but when and where shall it be called?

Comment: That is the question. There are too many child classes for me to copy+paste a base form call to every single one. I need an automated function or syntax which will force all forms to report their name when entered.

Comment: Well, I get stopped by "when entered" - what do you consider "entered". Created? Displayed? ... Of course you could add some reflection reporting in the BaseClass constructor, which is automatically called by every descendant... But I guess you want more something in the sense of when "Form.Show()" is called ...

Comment: Or totally different: Maybe an external Code-Analyzing Tool would help. There are tools that can detect and visualize code dependencies  ... just an idea.

Comment: When entered is a good event to consider, thank you! I am already using code-analysis tools to visualize dependencies. Right now I want to map out which source code is used in which part of the user interface. For instance when I enter Settings, it should pop up "You have entered the settings form". Problem is that there are too many forms for me to manually create this for each child. Hopefully that makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't overriden the `OnShown` method you can put it in the base form like this :

```
public /*abstract*/ class BaseForm : Form
{ 
    protected override void OnShown(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnShown(e);
        Console.WriteLine($"Entered {this.GetType().Name}");
    }
}
```

It will be called automatically when any of the forms is shown and print the name of the class to the console using Reflection.

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you very much, saves me a lot of time

Answer (score 0):

As I understand and as you said, If all forms Inherit from a base form, they all have components in common. So you can create a Module like bellow and put the methods of this base form.

```
'This Module you will put all methods from the base form

Module ProcAuxiliar

    Public Sub BaseForm_Sum (ByVal Textbox1 As String, ByVal Textbox2 As String)
        Dim Val1 As Int32 = Convert.ToInt32(Textbox1)
        Dim Val2 As Int32 = Convert.ToInt32(Textbox2)

        MsgBox( Convert.ToString(Val1 + Val2)

    End Sub

    Public Sub BaseForm_decrease (ByVal Textbox1 As String, ByVal Textbox2 As String)
        Dim Val1 As Int32 = Convert.ToInt32(Textbox1)
        Dim Val2 As Int32 = Convert.ToInt32(Textbox2)

        MsgBox( Convert.ToString(Val1 - Val2)

    End Sub

End Module
```

In Child Form  just call the method from module

```
'Child Form 1
    Sub BtSumClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btSum.Click
        ProcAuxiliar.BaseForm_Sum(Textbox1.Text, Textbox2.Text)
    End Sub

    'Child Form 2
    Sub BtDecreaseClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles BtDecrease.Click
        ProcAuxiliar.BaseForm_decrease(Textbox1.Text, Textbox2.Text)
    End Sub
```

Overrideing a method of a baseform in the children and calling the baseform method with more codes:

```
protected override sub Children_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        MyBase.Children_Load(sender, e)


    MyBase.BaseForm_Load(sender, e)


End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I apologize if I did not emphasize the issue clearly enough. There are too many forms for me to manually call the method from all the children. So I am looking for functionality that will allow me to create a base form method, and then press a few buttons or use some syntax which will force all children to call it without me spending hours copying the call into every child.

Comment: Let me see If I understand, You want to call a method in all children forms if they are open, for exemple, show a msgbox at 14pm for all open forms ?

Comment: Close! Let's say I start the application and it enters Main Menu Form. It should then pop up "You are in main menu form". Then I press Settings. It should pop up "You are now in settings form", and so on. There are too many forms for me to implement this manually for each child, basically

Comment: So, You'll realy have to use a base form and all others inherit from then, cause if you implement  "welcome" on method OnEnter in the baseform, it will be call automatically in the childrens and you will not need to implement "welcome" in all childrens. 

For the children forms call automatically  a method in base form, it have to be in a action, for example, onclick, onload, onclose. If you want to add more codes in the children, just override the method calling the base method as edited in the first aswer I did:

Comment: Yes you are right, that is what I am after. I implemented the code provided by Jakub Dąbek, and if I understand correctly you mean the same thing. Thank you for your help.